# Can't ask for 'publish_actions' permission

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, ticker

So here's the thing, I can't ask for 'publish_actions' permission for other users than Developers and Test Users.

And when I tried posting an action with a regular user I got an error like this one:
"(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions"

Also from the facebook documentation:

"While in Open Graph Beta, the 'publish_actions' permission can only be requested from developers and test users of your app. The 'publish_actions' permission will be ignored if requested from any other user."

.......

"Open Graph is still in beta. Though you can submit Open Graph actions for review in the Dev App, actions will not be approved until Timeline is available to all users."

Any clues on when this would be fully available for real apps ?

Answer (score 1):

Open Graph is still in beta, and will launch soon after Timeline has been rolled out. Only then will you be able to request publish_actions for non-developers of your app.

Answer (score 1):

1. go to the app's open graph
2. edit open graph
3. click the get code button
4. you gotta
5. confirm -> api explorer
6. and run app
7. but you will have the role developer
8. tester do not work.
9. because tester can't edit apps property.